# How JVM will extend the Object class for a custom class in java?

Tags: java, object

I heard for every class JVM will extended implicitly, but what is the need of extending it, without extending Object class, object cannot be created for a custom class? Please anyone explain clearly what will happen for every custom class when its object is creating?

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding what you are asking. Could you try to make it a little clearer?

Comment: If an object is not an `instanceof Object` then how do you serialize it !

Comment: @ChrisBode every custom class need to extend Object class for object creation rite, why JVM will extend custom class to Object class and what is the process involved in this?

Comment: The JVM extends nothing. It just takes the classes like they are defined in the class files. It just so happens that all classes ultimatly are derived from Object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Object` class contains all the common method. So implicit exetending by default gives you those common method, which reduce the overhead.

Methods are - `equals, wait, notify, notifyall, hashcode,getClass,clone etc`

If you need custom logic, so you can `override` that `method`.

*Note: All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of Object class.*

Comment: my question here is not what are all methods that are available in Object class, My question is why JVM extends the custom class to Object class?

Comment: :) I have written man, it gives defult methods in Object class, which reduce the overhead

Comment: @developer, I have provided the reason for the same. You can look into my answer also, it is supplementery for this good answer.

Comment: You are right, only for this reason the Object class is getting extended? or to object get instantaited JVM will extend the Object class?

Comment: We are not able to understand. What do you mean by JVM extend Object class?

Answer (score 1):

To provide this functinality by default, every class extends `Object` class.

- Consider to `equals` method of object class where object references
  are checked whether they refer to same object or not. If you don't
  provide an implementation of `equals()` method, then the default one
  will be called for custom objects also.
- The default `toString` method provides the class name and hashcode
  for the object. You don't need to write a separate one if you don't
  want other string representation of the object.
- The methods like `wait(), notify(), notifyAll()` provide
  functionality for thread communication for objects. So your classes
  do not have to do it externally. They can just extends `Object` class
  functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is related to the idea of inheritance in general - the idea of inheritance is that you define a common set of behaviors, that apply to all subclasses. Anything defined in the "Object" class is available to all classes you create.

It contains a few things that are applicable to every peace of information you use in your code:

- `equals and hashCode` methods to establish an equality theory within
  the given abstraction.
- `toString` to represent an object in human-readable (probably, only
  programmer-readable) format.
- `getClass` to provide reflection capabilities on the given abstraction;
     some methods to organize object-oriented runtime.

Java chose to make a single class be the ultimate parent class for everything so that there is an easy way to pass around any arbitrary object, without needing to know its type (i.e. you can use the declared type of Object to refer to every single item in the type system, even primitives using their wrapper classes). However, there are OOP languages such as C++ where there is no universal base class as in Java. Another benefit to having a universal base class is that logic dealing with the superclass does not have to be special cased for top-level classes (with the exception of the universal base class, Object, itself).

Answer (score 0):

`Object` class provides a root to hierarchy. That means, objects can be passed on, and expected for.

If your class does not extents object in some way, it can't be expected as an argument or passed as an parameter. It's useless.

Apart from that, Object class holds very very important methods that define many important operations of Java.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a class, you surely wants to create the instances of that class. Now, those instance must have some specific and some basic properties.

These basic properties are ready-made for you in `Object` class. That is why you implicitly extends Object class.

Specific properties of your custom class is defined by you in your custom class.

So, when you are creating an instance (object) of your custom class, then:

```
1. Object class properties are inherited by your custom class.
2. Your custom class specific properties are alloted to your instance. Hence, now your instance would have custom + Object properties.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object` class provide very common methods that are needed for almost every object in java

These the methods of class Object, which are summarized as follows [Accroding to JSL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)    :
1.The method clone is used to make a duplicate of an object.
2.The method `equals` defines a notion of object equality, which is based on value, not reference, comparison.
3.The method `finalize` is run just before an object is destroyed
4.The method `hashCode` is very useful, together with the method equals, in hashtables such as java.util.Hashmap.
5.The methods `wait, notify, and notifyAll` are used in concurrent programming using threads.
6.The method `toString` returns a String representation of the object.
7.The most important method is `getClass()` which returns `Class` object which contains
some metadata about the class:

```
name
package
methods
fields
constructors
annotations
```

So we can say each object in java is a respective `Class` object, which contains metadata about it, that is accessible at runtime by the `ClassLoader`.